# XGBoost: predict on only valuable features

Tags: r, scikit-learn, bigdata, xgboost

I have a somewhat strange case that I can't find an answer to anywhere. It is really only applicable if you have a legitimately large data set. Let me describe.

XGBoost returns feature importance for all variables in the model. I have been using a data set with over 1000 features and typically about 25-50% of them come back with non-zero feature importance.

Now I want to make predictions with this model. Imagine I am making predictions on A LOT of observations (over 1m, imagine predicting on incoming tweets or something). If I re-train the model, giving it only the columns that the original training picked out as valuable (non-zero importance), then the re-trained model makes predictions MUCH FASTER than the original, and WITH THE EXACT SAME ACCURACY. This last part makes sense, because it is building the exact same trees. Also, not only is it faster, but it takes up a lot less space in memory because you are passing it something like a 1m x 250 matrix instead of a 1m x 1000 matrix.

My question is: is there a way to train a model, and then pass the predict function only the features it actually uses *without having to re-train the model* to except only those features instead of the full matrix? This [blog post](http://machinelearningmastery.com/feature-importance-and-feature-selection-with-xgboost-in-python/) discusses a similar concept of using XGBoost for feature selection, but it does it by *retraining* the model each time.

The obvious answer is "just re-train it" but if I am using a lot of training observations then training the model takes awhile, so I would rather not have to retrain it if possible.

I am doing this in R, but solutions in Python/sklearn would also be helpful.
Thanks!

Comment: I don't believe this would be possible in python/sklearn implementation.  The model will expect the matrix size to be whatever was passed in for training, so making predictions on a smaller matrix will error.

Comment: Beyond what Hobbes said, this would require adding a complicated pruning mechanism. Due to the feature bootstrapping performed by these models, you'll very likely have feature importances such as 0.00001, not 0, which means the features are being used somewhere. I would just retrain the ensemble.

Comment: Thanks. I think you're both right that's it's not possible. I don't think it would be complicated though, it would just require the model taking note of the feature _names_ instead of just column indices. In my experience, if I train it on ~2k features, it returns ~750 or so with non-zero importance. Anyway, for now I think you're right that re-training is the only option. Thanks again.

Comment: There's no way to do it because XGB itself does not work like that. You can pass NA values but that still requires allocating them. So no, you'll have to redo your model with only the features that are used.